# SVN Add and Commit File using Command Line - Tortoise SVN

Tags: python, python-3.x, svn, command-line

On my machine Tortoise SVN is installed. I wanted to add and commit files using command line.
When I tried `svn add --force /path/to/your/project/*` command I am getting `'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command error.`

I also tried Tortoise commands:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit
                 /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt*c:\svn_wc\file2.txt"
                 /logmsg:"test log message" /closeonend:0

TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\svn_wc\" /closeonend:0

TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt"
                 /startrev:50 /endrev:60 /closeonend:0
```

It works but after hitting command SVN window will open. We need to click "OK" button manually.

Is there any way or commands to make automatically add and commit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if it is still actual but since I had the same issue not long ago, I think it's better to share some experience.

First of all, TortoiseSVN is a GUI tool, you need to use "svn" commands. Install command line tool, if you didnt.

[image]

Second, try something like this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\path_to_your_files
svn add * --force
svn commit -m ""
pause
```

Command "add * --force" will add all files, then they will be committed with empty message.

Hope it might help.